# PreferenceFragmentCompat Theme issue

Tags: android, android-theme, android-preferences

I'm using PreferenceFragmentCompat for my Preference Page

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat{


@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_page, rootKey);

 } }
```

and i'm using this Theme for my Activity which is setting my PreferenceFragmentCompat:

```
  <style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDarkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

but my Preference Page looks like this:
[Preference Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirsy.png)

then i added a custom style:

```
 <style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDarkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeCustom</item>
```

```
<style name="PreferenceThemeCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDarkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

and all was displayed well [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGN7M.png)
but when i click on a EditTextPreference i got the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dialog view must contain an EditText with id @android:id/edit
   at androidx.preference.EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onBindDialogView(EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:68)
   at androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onCreateDialog(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:149)
   at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:352)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1383)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1233)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1299)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:688)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2069)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1859)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1814)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1721)

at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:147)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)           
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run                         (Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

then i tried to define my custom preference style like this:

```
    <style name="PreferenceThemeCustom" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDarkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

But setting parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material" caused this problem again: [Preference Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirsy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<android:windowBackground="...">` with `<android:background="...">`, I guess that should help